# Unable to register app (iOS app) on Azure portal

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk

I am following the [link](https://medium.com/@bhushanthe06/onedrive-sdk-for-ios-swift-eebea2a4882) to integrate One Drive SDK into an existing iOS app. I have an free account created on azure portal. Its a work account so I can see a default Azure Active Directory.

During this process, I need to register the app on the Azure portal. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/app-registration?view=odsp-graph-online) for registering apps and generating app ID does not work in my case.

I am unable to create an app ID or access existing active Azure Directory details. The portal shows me restricted access page as mentioned in this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/352443/microsoft-azure-free-trial-no-access-to-acitive-di.html. The solutions mentioned in this link does not work for me as those options are not seen on the screen.

Any kind of help in understanding the trouble will be of great help!

Comment: Apparently you don't have permissions in AzureAD to register SPN. Note, that it's a different blade that Azure. You need either to get corresponding permissions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference or ask AAD team to register it for you.

Comment: Hi @Hardoman, I cannot view admin name or contact details of AAD team. Does the portal mention it anywhere? I could not find it.

Comment: No, AAD team is not mentioned anywhere because it's different in every company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to insuffient permissions as this is a free trial account.

Go to your Overview pane of your subscription and check if there are any directories present.

If not try creating a free trial account using a Work or school account and there you will be provided with a default directory. Then Create new Azure AD Tenant and then Connect your Azure free subscription to your new Azure AD Directory.

REFERENCES:

1. [Associate a subscription to a directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory#associate-a-subscription-to-a-directory).
2. [Create a new tenant for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-access-create-new-tenant#create-a-new-tenant-for-your-organization).

Comment: Its a work account so I can see a default Azure Active Directory but restricted access. Not sure how to contact the admin to get more access.

Comment: @MRR you have to find who is responsible for AAD in your company.